# ImportError: cannot import name 'abs' from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.backend

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, python-3.5

**Current Version Stacks:**

python 3.5

```
tensorflow                    1.14.0                
tensorflow-estimator          1.14.0                
tensorflow-gpu                1.14.0                
tensorflow-tensorboard        0.1.8 

protobuf                      3.9.1

Keras                         2.2.4                 
Keras-Applications            1.0.7                 
Keras-Preprocessing           1.0.9
```

**Drivers & Machine:**

```
Ubuntu 16.04 , NVIDIA-SMI 396.54 , CUDA - 9.0 , CuDnn 7 , libcudnn - 7.4.1
```

**Summary**-

Not able to import abs from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.backend on 
tensorflow-gpu == 1.14.0

And Not able to get CheckpointableBase attribute on tensorflow-gpu == 1.8.0

Which tensorflow-gpu and keras version supports both CheckpointableBase attribute and 'abs' from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.backend ?

**Details** -

I'm currently training matterport mask rcnn with Keras==2.2.4. According to some [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299194/importerror-cannot-import-name-abs) in order to get abs I have tried updating tensorflow-gpu to 1.8.0 , updating protobuf. Although I was then able to import abs, but end up reciveing " AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.training.checkpointable' has no attribute 'CheckpointableBase' " on tensorflow-gpu to 1.8.0. Then in order to get CheckpointableBase some threads pointed to again update tensorflow-gpu == 1.14.0.

**Traceback** :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kalpit/Desktop/palash/m-rcnn-traning/data/libraries/bacteria_rcnn_train.py", line 53, in <module>
    import keras 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/activations/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.activations import elu
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras import activations
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/activations.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras import backend as K
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/backend.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.layers import base as tf_base_layers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.backend import abs
ImportError: cannot import name 'abs'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hi,**

**I was able to resolve this issue by removing all the tensorFlow and keras python3 packages from dist-packages dir itself , uninstalling using pip3 and then again installing tensorflow==1.8.0

tensorflow-gpu==1.8.0 , Keras==2.2.4**

( The Potential reason which caused this specific erro was python referring multiple tensoflow-gpu,keras version packages files in  dis-packages dir. Although installing a specific tensoflow-gpu,keras version via pip3 should ideally remove previous existing versions. But In my case that didn't occurred.)

Solution:

1. Locate tensorflow , keras packages in dist-packages dir using `$ locate --basename '\tensorflow'` command (provided you are using Ubuntu). In my case it is

> $ locate --basename '\tensorflow'

outputs -

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow
/usr/share/nginx/html/projects/python/machine-learning/objectDetection/models-master/research/syntaxnet/tensorflow
```

&

> $ locate --basename '\keras'

outputs-

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/keras
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/keras
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/keras/api/keras
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/tools/api/generator/api/keras
/usr/share/nginx/html/projects/python/Playground/lambda/testkeras/keras
```

2. Now that you are aware of the desired packages location. Simply remove the tensorflow and keras dir's and uninstall packages using below commands

Removing dir's

```
sudo rm -R /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/
sudo rm -R /usr/share/nginx/html/projects/python/machine-learning/objectDetection/models-master/research/syntaxnet/tensorflow

sudo rm -R /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/
sudo rm -R /usr/share/nginx/html/projects/python/Playground/lambda/testkeras/keras
```

Uninstall using pip3

```
sudo pip3 uninstall tensorflow
sudo pip3 uninstall tensorflow-gpu
sudo pip3 uninstall keras
```

3. Again Installing tensorflow, tensorflow-gpu ,keras

   sudo pip3 install tensorflow==1.8.0
   sudo pip3 install tensorflow-gpu==1.8.0 
   sudo pip3 install Keras==2.2.4